# Performing a concurrency-proof update of a dictionary in Redis

Tags: python, redis

I am using `Redis` as a centralized in-memory data storage between different distributions of applications.

When all distributions of my application operate on the **same key**, I am afraid that a **concurrency** situation could occur. Take this example:

```
THIS_DISTRIBUTION_NAME = "Alpha1"

alive_distributions = redis.hmget('alive_distributions') # {"Charlie1": 1623234874}

alive_distributions[THIS_DISTRIBUTION_NAME] = int(time.time()) # {"Charlie1": 1623234874,"Alpha1": 1623234875}

redis.hmset('alive_machines', alive_distributions)
```

If *Charlie1* gets updated in-between *Alpha1*'s `hmget` and `hmset` operation, it would result in data inconsistency.

How can I perform a safe, transaction-like update of a dictionary without concurrency?

Answer (score 2):

Redis supports [transactions](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) and I would specifically look into the [check-and-set](https://redis.io/topics/transactions#cas) section of the documentation. Optimistic locking it's what you need.

#### Update #1

---

Assuming `redis-py` as your redis client you could do something like this:

```
pipe = redis.pipeline()
pipe.watch('some_key') # watch key 'some_key'
value = pipe.get('some_key')
pipe.multi() # start transaction
value = 'some_value'
pipe.set('some_key', value) # update 'some_key' with new value
pipe.execute() # will fail if some other process wrote to 'some_key' in the meantime
```

Comment: Please attach a code example for python as this question is python-related

Comment: My answer is redis related (as redis supports what you're looking for) but updated answer with a small example.

Answer (score 0):

The operation you are interested in may be wrapped in a MULTI/EXEC transaction in order to make sure both fields are updated or none.
The command itslef that you need is the zadd command. In fact with the zadd comand you can preset values to be indexed (updated) automatically after a period of time.